# Is it possible to create an HTML site that works with Java RMI?

Tags: java, html, rmi

I'm new to RMI and HTML.

If I have created an RMI server and a client (let's say my client has a method getString() that returns a string), can I create an HTML page that show the result from this method?

I'm not bound to HTML, I need to create a web page that will know to show data given to it with the RMI. Is it possible?

Comment: You will need a web server that will be the RMI client, and the RMI server that will work as data source for your web application. It can be done, but it demands a high amount of work, and this approach has evolved with the time in order to use other technologies like Web Services or remote EJB (this one uses RMI behind the scenes for you).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza - thanks. I'll try and switch to Web Services. thanks!